# How can I find the positions from characters in a string with string::find?

Tags: c++

I need the positions of characters in a string.
The String contains:

```
"username":"secret", "password":"also secret", "id":"secret too", "token":"secret"
```

and I need the positions of the quotation marks from the token that are bold: "token":**"**secret**"**.
I have experimented with the code from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find
but everything didn't work. Can anyone help me?
Here is what i have tried but it only gives out a 0:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string buffer("\"username\":\"secret\", \"password\":\"also secret\", \"id\":\"secret too\", \"token\":\"secret\"");
    size_t found = buffer.find('"');
    if (found == std::string::npos)std::cout << "something went wrong\n";
    if (found != std::string::npos)
        std::cout << "first " << '"' << " found at: " << found << '\n';
    for (int j = 0; j <= 17; ++j) {
        found = buffer.find('"');
        found + 1, 6;
        if (found != std::string::npos)
            std::cout << "second " << '"' << " found at : " << found << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Every time you call `buffer.find('"')`, it finds the same quote character - the first in the string.  Now, `find()` takes an optional second parameter - the position from which to start looking. Use that wisely.

Comment: Is this JSON data? If so I advise using a proper JSON library rather than doing string manipulation by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many possible solutions. So, it is hard to answer.

What basically needs to be done, is to iterate through the string, position by position, then check if the character is the searched one, and then do something with the result.

A first simple implementation could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const std::string buffer("\"username\":\"secret\", \"password\":\"also secret\", \"id\":\"secret too\", \"token\":\"secret\"");

int main() {

    for (size_t position{}, counter{}; position < buffer.length(); ++position) {

        if (buffer[position] == '\"') {
            ++counter;
            std::cout << "Character \" number " << counter << " found at position " << position << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But then, your question was about the usage of `std::string.find()`. In your implementation, you start always the search at the beginning of the `std::string`. And because of that, you will always find the same " at position 0.

Solution: After you have found the first match, use the resulting `pos` (incremented by one) as the second parameter to the `std::string.find()` function. Then you will start the search after the first found " and hence find the next one. And all this can be done in a normal `for`-loop.

See below the next easy example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const std::string buffer("\"username\":\"secret\", \"password\":\"also secret\", \"id\":\"secret too\", \"token\":\"secret\"");

int main() {

    for (size_t position{}, counter{}; std::string::npos != (position = buffer.find("\"", position)); ++position, ++counter) {

        std::cout << "Character \" number " << counter << " found at position " << position << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There are more solutions, depending on what you really want to do. You coud extract all keywords and data with a simple regex.

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>

const std::regex re{ R"(\"([ a-zA-Z0-9]+)\")" };

const std::string buffer("\"username\":\"secret\", \"password\":\"also secret\", \"id\":\"secret too\", \"token\":\"secret\"");

int main() {
    std::vector part(std::sregex_token_iterator(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), re, 1), {});
    std::cout << part[7] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Or, you can split everything into tokens and values. Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>

const std::regex re1{ "," };
const std::regex re2{ R"(\"([^\"]+)\")" };

const std::string buffer("\"username\":\"secret\", \"password\":\"also secret\", \"id\":\"secret too\", \"token\":\"secret\"");

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> block(std::sregex_token_iterator(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), re1, -1), {});
    std::map<std::string, std::string> entry{};
    for (const auto& b : block) {
        std::vector blockPart(std::sregex_token_iterator(b.begin(), b.end(), re2, 1), {});
        entry[blockPart[0]] = blockPart[1];
    }

    for (const auto& [token, value] : entry)
        std::cout << std::setw(20) << token << " --> " << value << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

But if you have a complex given format, like JSON, there are so many special cases that the only meaningful approach is to use an existing library.